# How to create a variable in Jade with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have the following code in Jade for my AngularJS app:

`td (ng-style="{ 'background': getColour(data[0].prob) }")
    |  {{ cellValue(data[0].prob) }}`

As you can see I have some repetition of `data[0].prob`, how can I make this a variable in Jade, so that it doesn't fetch the value every time I call it?

Bare in mind that `data[0].prob` is defined the controller of this template file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable

```
- var color = data[0].prob
```

And interpolate the variable in `ngStyle` directive using `#{}`:

```
td (ng-style="{ 'background': getColour(#{color}) }")
```

Or do simple JavaScript native concatenation using `+`

```
td (ng-style="{ 'background': getColour(" + color + ") }")
```